# Getting the angles of a triangle

Tags: geometry, triangles

I am having trouble with the following question

> > In the following figure if PQ=QS and QR=RS and angle PRS is 100 degrees what is the measure of angle QPS (Ans = 20)

[image]

Now here is how far i got:
Since QR=RS its angles would be same and we know that PRS is 100 so we get

2a + 100 = 180 so a = 40 so RQS is 40 and QSR is 40 . Am I doing this correct ? How will i get PSQ or QPS ? (I need to do this without Trign. ratios)

Comment: Correct so far. Now ... Knowing $\angle RQS$ gives you $\angle PQS$. And since $\triangle PQS$ is isosceles, you can get $\angle QPS$ and $\angle QSP$.

Answer (score 2):

So far so good!  Now noticing that $\angle QRS + \angle QPS + \angle QSP + \angle QSR = 180$, then just like you did before, since $\triangle PQS$ is isosceles, $\angle QPS = \angle QSP$.  So plugging in,

$100 + 2 \angle QPS + 40 = 180$ and $\angle QPS = 20$!

Comment: In general for questions like these, whenever you get stuck, try and use the information you haven't yet worked into the problem.